# How to use {old,new}name inside a shell script variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

First, what is the name these transformations you can do with linux shell?

```
$ echo {old,new}name
oldname newname
```

---

I tried to put then on a variable, as:

```
$ var={old,new}name
$ echo $var
{old,new}name
```

But they stop working, as we may see. I need them on a variable to allow easily change them on bulk operations as:

```
mv {old,new}name/"file 1.txt"
mv {old,new}name/"file 2.txt"
mv {old,new}name/"file 3.txt"
mv {old,new}name/"file 4.txt"
```

So I could write them as:

```
var={old,new}

mv '$var'name/"file 1.txt"
mv '$var'name/"file 2.txt"
mv '$var'name/"file 3.txt"
mv '$var'name/"file 4.txt"
```

Also, I had trouble putting together the shell variable and the `name` complement i.e., `$varname`. I figured out to use single quotes around the `$var` name, i.e., `'$var'name`. Thought, is it the best way to do it?

Comment: The only expansions that happen *after* parameter substitution are string-splitting and globbing. Brace expansion happens *before* values are expanded. There are compelling security-involved reasons why this was true (if arbitrary data were parsed as syntax, you could basically *never* write a script in bash that handled files with untrusted names).

Comment: ...so, the short answer is "you can't do it *for good reasons*, and trying to find workarounds (as with `eval`) will compromise security unless done with great care".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to evaluate contents of a variabele when you do not need to.
One of the alternatives is writing a function.

```
function oldnewname { mv oldname/"$1" newname/"$1" }
oldnewname "file 1.txt"
oldnewname "file 2.txt"
oldnewname "file 3.txt"
oldnewname "file 4.txt"
```

When the name is dynamic, you can change your function

```
function oldnew { mv old"$1"/"$2" new"$1"/"$2" }
oldnew name "file 1.txt"
oldnew name "file 2.txt"
oldnew name "file 3.txt"
oldnew name "file 4.txt"
```

EDIT:
Since I migrated to Linux and Bash I neglect POSIX. As @Charles commented, more portable is

```
oldnewname()
{
  mv oldname/"$1" newname/"$1"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You answer fix my problem with a nice looking code.

Comment: Why use non-POSIX function declaration syntax here? The approach is a good one, but the code used to implement it is somewhat gratuitously incompatible with `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I used `function`a long time in Solaris and AIX environments with `ksh`. I shold have reconsidered my style, using something like https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73854/57293 .

Answer (score 3):

You can store the expansion *results* in an array:

```
var=( {old,new}name )      # performs expansion, stores results in var
printf '%s\n' "${var[@]}"  # prints "oldname" and "newname"
```

However, brace expansion is done *after* parameter expansion (that is, substitution of variables' values). This is for compelling reasons: If data were parsed as code, it would be impossible to write scripts handling untrusted data in bash.

---

Frankly, for your sample code, it's shorter just to write it thusly:

```
for name in name/"file "{1,2,3,4}.txt; do
  mv -- old"$name" new"$name"
done
```

---

That said, if you want to do the dangerous, insecure-without-extreme-caution thing, an approach to that caution might look thus:

```
var='{old,new}'
for f in "file 1.txt" "file 2.txt" "file 3.txt" "file 4.txt"; do
  printf -v cmd 'mv %sname/%q' "$var" "$name" && eval "$cmd"
done
```

Here, we're using `%s` to substitute the brace expansion (hand-written, trusted code), and `%q` to substitute the (presumably untrusted) filenames.

Comment: Thanks for all the explanations and time!